# .NET 2 to .NET 4 migration results in stack overflow crash

Tags: c++, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, stack-overflow

I have a legacy software with C++ and C# code, which worked in Windows XP SP3 and .NET 2.0 (VS2005). The software did scanning and image processing with plenty of memory intensive processing. The PC has 2gb RAM. The stack size is reserved to 15MB for the software process.

This software was migrated to .NET4 (VS2010). During the migration, code logic is not altered. The software works properly for individual scans and processing. However, for continous job runs the software crashes at random places. For all the crashes, the event viewer shows 'The software was terminated due to stack overflow'. On debugging the crash dump, it points to ntdll.dll (kernel dll).

To fix the issue following solutions were tried. None of them worked.

1. Stack size increased to 20MB. Software crashed.
2. Process is allocated 820 MB by VirtualAlloc in the beginning. This was increased to 1024 MB. It delayed the crash by a day. But eventually it crashed.
3. alloca was used to allocate memory for local variables. These were replaced by _malloca.

Please let me know if .NET 4 migration requires major increase in RAM to run the software without failure. Inputs on memory requirement change for .net 2 to .net 4 migration are welcome.

Comment: Does the process memory increase while it is running?

Comment: Seems a sleeping bug got some action

Comment: 'The software was terminated due to **stack overflow**' Rats! They caught us! Run for it!

Comment: Process memory used remains somewhat static around 1GB. Virtual memory allocation ranges close to 1.3GB.